# UITableViewCell shifting up with custom segue appear/dismiss

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uinavigationbar, segue

I have a MasterViewController, using a custom modal segue, presents a detail view. The custom modal animation is [LCZoomTransition](https://github.com/mluisbrown/LCZoomTransition) from mluisbrown on GitHub. Currently, I am experiencing an issue that causes my tableview's cells to shift upward on selection.
[image: Maybe AutoLayout?]

I have no idea what could be causing this. My code to present the detail view:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    EditViewController *edit = [[EditViewController alloc]init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *mo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [edit setManagedObjectContext:mo];



    id appDelegate= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];


    OweInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.editView = edit;


    self.editView.delegate = self;
    self.editView.info = info;

    edit.info = info;
    edit.delegate = self;
    edit.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];



    self.editView.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToEdit" sender:self];



}
```

and my segue code:

```
if([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"pushToEdit"]){


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.zoomTransition.sourceView = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
               // pass the custom transition to the destination controller
        // so it can use it when setting up its gesture recognizers
        [[segue destinationViewController] setGestureTarget:self.zoomTransition];
    EditViewController *edit = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSManagedObjectContext *mo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [edit setManagedObjectContext:mo];


        id appDelegate= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];


        OweInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            self.editView = edit;


        self.editView.delegate = self;
        self.editView.info = info;
    self.editView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    edit.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        edit.info = info;
        edit.delegate = self;





    }
```

Anyone know what might be causing this? This is on iOS 8 and Xcode 6.

What it is supposed to look like:
[image: Workin]

Comment: @meda it might not be apparent in the gif, but the UITableViewCell shifts upwards on transition (both to detail and back), not normal

Comment: But do you get an actual layout error or did you mean an issue ? I can only notice the right UIBarButton move a little bit

Comment: @meda no, I realize my wording was wrong in the original comment. The UITableViewCell shifts up, which should not happen in this transition. I'll post a Gif of what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are duplicating multiple controllers.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should contain the call for segue.

Then create only one instance of the viewController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToEdit" sender:self];
}
```

That's it, you do the rest in the segue delegate, and avoid duplicating instances.

Comment: just tried, still happening. See post for the gif of how it is supposed to look like